# ANOVA result is inconsistent (AIC VS deviance)

Tags: statistics, anova, multilevel-analysis, model-comparison

I am working on GLM models (using glmer). Now I am exploring whether I need an interaction term. I'd like to find the best model,  but the following result is confusing:

```
Models:
g1: y ~ year + (1 | BZR/PLR)
g2: y ~ year + year * BZR + (1 | BZR/PLR)
   Df  AIC   BIC  logLik  deviance Chisq Chi Df Pr(>Chisq)    
g1 11 16580 16664 -8279.2  16558                             
g2 90 16612 17296 -8215.8  16432  126.87     79 0.0005135 ***
```

AIC is better in g1 while g2 shows better logLiK and deviance. Which model do I have to select?

Thank you very much for all the comments in advance!!

Best, 
Aekyung